# define for mysql connect

Tags: php, mysql, html

My situation:
Folder structure is  /resources/website/inc/ (/resources/ is where configs are stored, /website/ holds index.php and /inc/

I have defined my constants for db connection in  config.php / in resources folder.

```
   define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
   define ( 'DB_USER', 'my_username' );
   define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'my_password' );
   define ( 'DB_NAME', 'my_database' );
```

In index.php the database is accessed and displays data.

I've come to the conclusion that it am trying to use the defined constants in config.php with a connect statement in index.php, but the constants are not passing.

This is my connect statement:

```
$connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or 
                         die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

When i add both pieces into the config.php it works fully, but i wanted to have connect and close of connection in various areas, i do not want to have to define the variables again

Comment: Are you requiring the configuration file?

Comment: Q: but i wanted to have connect and close of connection in various areas, i do not want to have to define the variables again  A: Isn't that what ".inc" files are for?  Why not create an include file, and "include''" or "require_once()"?

Comment: its appears i have semi fixed this by keeping the connection open.
i was using include and trying to use the constants from another file which was set to inlcude('../config.php')
Problem was not passing the data

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to require (include) the config file in every other file that can be accessed through the web server.

Something alone the lines of:

`config.php`

```
define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'my_username' );
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'my_password' );
define ( 'DB_NAME', 'my_database' );
```

`public/index.php`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
// The rest of you code here
```

`public/contact.php`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
// The rest of you code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="container text-center">
    
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder=""> <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder=""> <br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="dugme" id="dugme" class="btn btn-sm ">signin</button>
        <div id="answer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>


      index.js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dugme").click(function(){
            let unetEmail=$("#email").val();
            let unetaLozinka=$("#lozinka").val();
            $.post("login.php",{email: unetEmail, lozinka: unetaLozinka}, function(response){
                $("#odgovor").html(response)
            })
        })
    }) 

login.php 

    <?php
    session_start();
    
    if(isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['lozinka'])&&$_POST['email']!=""&&$_POST['lozinka']!=""){
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $lozinka=$_POST['lozinka'];
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
        $db=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pva_k2");
        if(!$db){
            die("greska prilikom prijave na bazu, greska je ".mysqli_connect_errno().": ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $upit="SELECT * from korisnici where email='$email' and lozinka='$lozinka'";
        $rez=mysqli_query($db,$upit);
        if(mysqli_error($db)!=""){
            echo "greska pri izvrsavanju upita ".mysqli_errno($db).": ".mysqli_error($db);
        }else{
            if(mysqli_num_rows($rez)==1){
                while($red=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
                    $_SESSION['ime'] = $red['ime'];
                    $_SESSION['prezime'] = $red['prezime'];
                    $_SESSION['status']=$red['status'];
                    $_SESSION['korisnikid']=$red['id'];
                }
                
                echo '<script>window.location.href = "posts.php";</script>';
                exit();
            }else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Uneti podaci ne odgovaraju ni jednom korisniku</div><br>";
            }
        }
    
        mysqli_close($db);
    }else echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Svi podaci moraju biti uneti</div><br>";
    ?>
```

Comment: you can use <?php
    session_start();

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    
    echo '<a href="index.php">Back to main</a>';
?> FOR LOGout